# AttributeError: 'myGrid' object has no attribute 'clicked'

Tags: python, kivy

I am getting the error.I have seen all the answers of similar type of questions. Most of them had problems in the .kv file.I have no .kv file.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class myGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "First Name: "))
        self.firstname = TextInput()
        self.inside.add_widget(self.firstname)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name: "))
        self.lastName = TextInput()
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput()
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

        def pressed(self, instance):
            print("clicked")
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your current example is `AttributeError: 'myGrid' object has no attribute 'pressed'`, since you change the method's name.

The problem is your indentation.

This code works:

```py
class myGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "First Name: "))
        self.firstname = TextInput()
        self.inside.add_widget(self.firstname)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name: "))
        self.lastName = TextInput()
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput()
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        print("clicked")
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```